# On the quantum computer implementation of FFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, fourier-transform, quantum-computer, ising-model

In Fig. 1 of the paper [Exact Ising model simulation on a quantum computer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07112), it appears a circuit to implement a Bogoliubov and (discrete) fast Fourier transform (FFT) over 4 qubits  in order to diagonalize the Ising Hamiltonian.

My problem is that I don't understand why the FFT that should act over all qubits (since it is defined as a sum over positions as in Eq. (9) of the paper; or momenta if you perform the inverse as in Fig. 1) is applied by pairs of qubits and the reason why the modes $k = \{0, 1\}$ are the **only** ones playing some role. The total number of modes is 4 for 4 qubits and they are $k = \{-1, 0, 1, 2\}$, vid. Eq. (8).